# Can a directional derivative be negative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I just calculated the directional derivative of a function and ended up with $- \frac{1}{3}$ which seems counterintuitive. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Directional derivative is the change along that direction, it could be positive, negative, or zero. The directional derivative being negative means that the function decreases along that direction, or equivalently, increases along the opposite direction.

Comment: It can also be zero. Although you do answer the question of whether this is possible, I think the OP needs to know why (algebraically) and how to interpret the negative result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I occasionally slip into the (non-universal) Bourbakistic tradition of including zero into positive (and correspondingly negative) with the expression strictly positive (negative) for the exclusion of zero. I've edited my answer to clarify and added interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example partial derivatives are directional derivatives. And partial derivatives can be negative.